# Creating multiple transitional buttons from 1 image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple looking image of different coloured bars which 'fan' left to right, a bit like the choc bars here:

http://www.lifeafterbagels.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Fanned-Bars.jpg

I want to turn into each bar into individual buttons with tooltip 'pop-ups' and colour changes when the cursor hovers over them. Very much like this image map:

http://winstonwolf.pl/clickable-maps/europe.html

I have looked at the map source code and it doesn't really help me, but from searching on this forum it looks like I need to use x and y coordinates to determine the area that would be 'clickable'. Is this correct?

I found some code which allowed me to create a transition between 2 images, which is great, but when the image is not a simple square inside a square div I run into trouble. This is the code for the simple transition:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("img.a").hover(
function() {
jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
```

and the CSS:

```
![div.fadehover {
    position:relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }][2]
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks

J

Comment: You could use CSS3 to rotate your images or transparent DIVs (action areas)

Comment: So do you have a single image like the fanned bars link? Or can you break the images up into one image per bar? The later would be a lot easier and neater if you can.

Comment: Yeah I could chop the images up individually, but would I struggle to position/rotate them so they're in the same position?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comment, this JS fiddle may be how you could rotate your images and set click/hover events for them.

http://jsfiddle.net/pSPX6/

Doing it this way will mean that you don't need to get into mouse coordinates yourself, just let jQuery/JavaScript sort them out for you! :)

As for the tooltip, you could always position it based on the parameters given to you in the hover event, the parameters passed to this events should contain the x and y coordinates of the mouse which you can then use to position the tooltip. For more info on the hover event I've used, see the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Hope this helps!

Let me know if you want more clarification!

Comment: Wow that is spot on! Thanks Andy I shall try that, many thanks!

Comment: No worries, feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it's helped you (The green tick under the score) :)